# Change vimtutor language

Tags: microsoft-windows, help-system

My vimtutor is in portuguese. I don't know why, because my Windows OS is in english, so as everything else. I don't remember to have chosen "portuguese" anywhere in the vim installing process.

How do I change it to english?

Comment: It may be a ... VI.rus ! (just kidding). I'd simply install a recent Vim, e.g. https://bintray.com/veegee/generic/vim_x64.

Comment: @VanLaser Haha - no. `vimtutor en` starts it in english, however this is not the default. If I do `vimtutor` only, it opens up in portuguese.

Comment: What the value of `v:lang`? `:echo v:lang`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It's PT (portuguese). Is this what I need to change?

Comment: So that's the source of the problem ;-) [`:help v:lang`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3alang) tells me it should be inherited from the OS (Windows in your case), or set explicitly by the user with the `:language` command ... But that won't help you, since the tutor file has already been loaded in the wrong language...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker So what is the solution?

Comment: I don't know ;-) If I had one, I would have offered it. Perhaps one of your locale settings is in Portuguese? There's a control panel thingy to set this (`Clock, Language, and Region`, and then `Region and Language`).

Comment: It's a long shot, but do you have `set encoding=utf-8` in your vimrc?

Answer (score 8):

### 1'st method

Run `vimtutor` (from command line) with 2 letter language code like:

`vimtutor en` (for English)

`vimtutor pt` (for Portuguese)

etc...

### 2'nd method

Open tutor with different language with:

`vim /usr/share/vim/vim74/tutor/tutor` (for English)

`vim /usr/share/vim/vim74/tutor/tutor.pt` (for Portuguese)

etc...

(The same default path applies to Cygwin on Windows. You may want to change `vim74` part if you have different version)

Using this method you may actually want to copy the file somewhere else first and then open the copy, because you are going to modify it.

### 3'rd method

Vimtutor opens in Portuguese by default because you probably have some environmental variable set to Portugese like: `LC_ALL`, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` (check it with `env | grep -P 'LC_ALL|LANG'`. You may want to change it like this:

`export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8`

and then run `vimtutor`.

Comment: Note that directly editing the tutor files (your "2nd method") is probably not a good idea. The `vimtutor` program *copies* this file to a temporary file, so you can muck about at your leisure and not foul anything up ;-) I recommend you do that, instead.

Comment: Yes, it is written in the answer (copying the file somewhere else).

Comment: By the way, the language code has minimally, not necessarily, two letters. Open, e. g., the vimtutor in Bavarian with "vimtutor bar".

Answer (score 0):

This method works well:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

For the Russian language, for example, then it is necessary to dial the following line:

```
vimtutor ru
```

for Portuguese

```
vimtutor pt
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but both of the methods you describe here were described one year ago in the other answer.